# torch7: Setting Variable Learning Rates for Different Conv-net Layers

Tags: lua, training-data, torch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to fine-tune a conv-net. It has the following structure (adapted from **OverFeat**):

```
   net:add(SpatialConvolution(3, 96, 7, 7, 2, 2))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(96, 256, 7, 7, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(256, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(512, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(512, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(1024, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(1024, 4096, 5, 5, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(4096, 4096, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(4096, total_classes, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.View(total_classes))
   net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())
```

And I'm using **SGD** as the optimization method with the following parameters:

```
   optimState = {
      learningRate = 1e-3,
      weightDecay = 0,
      momentum = 0,
      learningRateDecay = 1e-7
   }
   optimMethod = optim.sgd
```

I am training it as follows:

```
optimMethod(feval, parameters, optimState)
```

where:

```
-- 'feval' is the function with the forward and backward passes on the current batch
    parameters,gradParameters = net:getParameters()
```

From my references, I have learned that while fine-tuning a pre-trained network, it is recommended that the lower (convolutional) layers should have lower learning rates and the higher layers should have relatively higher learning rates.

I referred to torch7's documentation of [optim/sgd](https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/sgd.lua) to set different learning rates for each layer. From there, I get that setting **config.learningRates** i.e. a vector of individual learning rates, I can achieve what I want. I am new to Torch, so, please pardon me if this seems as a silly question, but it would be really helpful if someone can please explain me how and where to create/use this vector to serve my purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer, as you posted this question one year ago.

Anyway, just in case someone sees this, I've written a [post here](http://www.thedataware.com/post/the-torch-adventures-setting-layer-wise-training-parameters) about how to set different learning rates for different layers in torch.

The solution is to use `net:parameters()` instead of `net:getParameters()`. Instead of returning two tensors, it returns two tables of tensors, containing the parameters (and the gradParameters) for each layer in separate tensors.

In this way, you can run an `sgd()` step (with a different learning rate) for each layer. You can find the full code by clicking the above link.